# Using coalesce to create a view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, coalesce

I am creating a view with below script from 3 tables. I am having problems when a HCPCS is found in MUES_OUT_2010_07 and MUES_DME_2010_07 and not in MUES_PHY_2010_07

```
CREATE VIEW MUES AS
SELECT COALESCE(TPHY.HCPCS, TOUT.HCPCS, TDME.HCPCS) AS HCPCS
, COALESCE(UNITS_PHY, -1) AS UNITS_PHY
, COALESCE(UNITS_OUT, -1) AS UNITS_OUT
, COALESCE(UNITS_DME, -1) AS UNITS_DME
FROM MUES_PHY_2010_07 TPHY
FULL OUTER JOIN MUES_OUT_2010_07 TOUT
ON TPHY.HCPCS = TOUT.HCPCS
FULL OUTER JOIN MUES_DME_2010_07 TDME
ON TPHY.HCPCS = TDME.HCPCS
GO
```

My tables are created like below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MUES_OUT_2010_07](
    [HCPCS] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [UNITS_OUT] [smallint] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MUES_OUT_2010_07] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [HCPCS] ASC
)WITH FILLFACTOR = 90 ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MUES_DME_2010_07](
        [HCPCS] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
        [UNITS_DME] [smallint] NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_MUES_DME_2010_07] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [HCPCS] ASC
    )WITH FILLFACTOR = 90 ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MUES_PHY_2010_07](
            [HCPCS] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
            [UNITS_PHY] [smallint] NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_MUES_DME_2010_07] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [HCPCS] ASC
        )WITH FILLFACTOR = 90 ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO

insert into MUES_OUT_2010_07 select 'E1036', 1
insert into MUES_DME_2010_07 select 'E1036', 1
```

i expect the view to create a one record like below since HCPCS 'E1036' is not in the MUES_PHY_2010_07 table

HCPCS   UNITS_PHY  UNITS_OUT UNITS_DME

E1036   -1            1         1

but it creates two records like below

E1036   -1  -1  1

E1036   -1  1   -1

what am i doing wrong in the view

Comment: I don't think the problem is on the coalesce.  I think it has more to do with the two full outer joins.  Either not enough unique criteria exist to generate only one row on the joins, OR a table has 2 records unexpectedly when you only have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `full outer join`.  That means that you have to be careful, because a value could be missing from *any* table.  In particular, when you get to the third table, the `on` conditions need to refer to *both* the previous tables, in case one or the other is missing.

So, this might fix your problem:

```
CREATE VIEW MUES AS
    SELECT COALESCE(TPHY.HCPCS, TOUT.HCPCS, TDME.HCPCS) AS HCPCS,
           COALESCE(UNITS_PHY, -1) AS UNITS_PHY,
           COALESCE(UNITS_OUT, -1) AS UNITS_OUT,
           COALESCE(UNITS_DME, -1) AS UNITS_DME
    FROM MUES_PHY_2010_07 TPHY FULL OUTER JOIN
         MUES_OUT_2010_07 TOUT
         ON TPHY.HCPCS = TOUT.HCPCS FULL OUTER JOIN
         MUES_DME_2010_07 TDME
         ON COALESCE(TPHY.HCPCS, TOUT.HCPCS) = TDME.HCPCS;
```

Comment: Yes. @user176047 You'll probably find it much easier to follow if you simplify the scenario a lot, e.g. Remove the COALESCE and all the columns (since it's the number of rows that you want different you can just change to select * till you get the rows right).

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. The Coalesce at the end fixed the problem and simplifying the scenario made me understand.

Comment: @user176047 . . . Full outer joins are more complicated than they seem.  Occasionally they are necessary.  I would be likely to solve your problem using `union all` and `group by` -- although the joins may perform better.